# How to override entity pluralisation?

Tags: api-platform.com

I've started playing around with API Platform and it's looking like a fantastic but of kit and generally a quick Google or Stack Overflow search answers and questions I might have.

However, this one I'm struggling with and it could be a simple terminology issue...

How do I go about changing or overriding the automatic pluralisation of entity names? I.e. Fleet is becoming Fleets.

Any tips on where to look for documentation or any quick examples of how to do what I'm after? I'm using annotations.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom Operation Path Resolver which doesn't use Inflector::pluralize().

There is section in docs about it (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operation-path-naming/#create-a-custom-operation-path-resolver).

It requires creating custom class which implements OperationPathResolverInterface (https://github.com/api-platform/core/blob/master/src/PathResolver/OperationPathResolverInterface.php)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However it still unclear to me how can we use the custom path resolver per entity? In the documentation it is explained how to register it globally for the whole application. The user might have just a single entity, like in the question, called `Fleet`, which doesn't need pluralisation, but the other entities need pluralisation.