# Turn off pluralisation for an endpoint in APi Platform

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com

In a Symfony 5 project we're using the APi Platform to generate a REST API.

One of the entity classes is called `FarmMetadata`.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use  ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Table(... some settings ...)
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class FarmMetadata
{
    // properties and methods
}
```

When I run `php bin/console debug:router` it shows the following routes for this resource:

```
api_farm_metadatas_get_collection    GET      ANY      ANY    /api/farm_metadatas.{_format}        
api_farm_metadatas_post_collection   POST     ANY      ANY    /api/farm_metadatas.{_format}        
api_farm_metadatas_get_item          GET      ANY      ANY    /api/farm_metadatas/{id}.{_format}   
api_farm_metadatas_delete_item       DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/farm_metadatas/{id}.{_format}   
api_farm_metadatas_put_item          PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/farm_metadatas/{id}.{_format}   
api_farm_metadatas_patch_item        PATCH    ANY      ANY    /api/farm_metadatas/{id}.{_format}
```

However the word "metadata" is already plural. There's no such thing as metadatas. How can I turn off the pluralisation for this endpoint?

I tried using `shortName`:

```
* @ApiResource(
*     shortName="FarmMetadata" // also "farm_metadata"
* )
```

but it doesn't change the output.

If I use:

```
* @ApiResource(
*     shortName="Metadata"
* )
```

then the route names and paths are changed:

```
api_metadata_get_collection         GET      ANY      ANY    /api/metadata.{_format}              
api_metadata_post_collection        POST     ANY      ANY    /api/metadata.{_format}              
api_metadata_get_item               GET      ANY      ANY    /api/metadata/{id}.{_format}         
api_metadata_delete_item            DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/metadata/{id}.{_format}         
api_metadata_put_item               PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/metadata/{id}.{_format}         
api_metadata_patch_item             PATCH    ANY      ANY    /api/metadata/{id}.{_format}
```

but that's not what I want.

I know that I can declare a path for every operation, but that would hurt the DRY principle.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to override entity pluralisation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55685442/how-to-override-entity-pluralisation)

Comment: Thanks! That doesn't answer my question. I checked the documentation thoroughly and read that already. I don't see how to use the custom path resolver for a single entity. It shows how to register your custom path resolver in the app configuration.

Answer (score 4):

You could use "path" option on each operation.
Cf https://api-platform.com/docs/core/operations/#configuring-operations

For example

```
 *     shortName="Metadata",
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={
 *              "path"="/metadata/{id}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible by configuration: these routes are built in the private method `ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Symfony\Routing\ApiLoader::addRoute` (at least in v2.6 which I'm using), and this uses a static call to a pluralizer - so: decorating the ApiLoader is not easily possible (as the addRoute method is private), and exchanging the ways of generating the route is not possible (due to the usage of a static method call).

Looks like you need to open a feature request ticket in their bug tracker...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really very annoying that such a simple and common requirement isn't implemented.

Answer (score 1):

you can do easily as you want

```yaml
api_platform:
    ...
    path_segment_name_generator: App\InfraStructure\ApiPlatform\Core\SingularPathSegmentNameGenerator
```

- create SingularPathSegmentNameGenerator

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\InfraStructure\ApiPlatform\Core;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Operation\PathSegmentNameGeneratorInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Util\Inflector;

final class SingularPathSegmentNameGenerator implements PathSegmentNameGeneratorInterface
{
    public function getSegmentName(string $name, bool $collection = true): string
    {
        return Inflector::tableize($name);
    }
}
```